# Using JSP Scriplet along with JSON Model attributes

Tags: java, json, jsp, date, scriptlet

I am getting an attribute/parameter from JSON response as EPOCH time variable.
I want to convert into `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format and display in the table

```
<tbody>
    <c:if
        test="${not empty jsonResult && not empty jsonResult.records}">
        <c:forEach items="${jsonResult.records}" var="record">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:15%;"><img src="${record.attributes.P_Image_Path}" class="img-responsive" /></td>
                <td style="width:15%;">${record.attributes.P_Description}</td>
                <td style="width:55%;">${record.attributes.P_Username_Seller}</td>
                <%
                    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                    System.out.println(sdf.format( new java.util.Date(${record.attributes.P_Close_Time}));
                %>
                <td style="width:15%;">${record.attributes.P_Close_Time}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</tbody>
```

But it's unable to compile the JSP. I couldn't find how to use combination of scriplet and model attribute value from JSON

**Update**
Tried this - not working

```
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date(${record.attributes.P_Close_Time}%>" />
<td style="width: 15%;"><fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" value="${now}" /></td>
```

Tried this - not working

```
<td style="width: 15%;"><fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" value="<%=new java.util.Date(${record.attributes.P_Close_Time})%>" /></td>
```

Tried this - not working

```
<td style="width: 15%;"><fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" value="<%=new java.util.Date(record.attributes.P_Close_Time)>" /></td>
```

Comment: you cannot use `${...}` inside `<% ... %>`

Comment: @MicheleMariotti, may be :) Solution please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JSTL tags

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>


<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" value="${now}" />
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatdate_tag.htm

Comment: I am getting below error
Cannot convert 1377820800 of type class java.lang.String to class java.util.Date

Comment: convert first the `record.attributes.P_Close_Time` to `DateTime` before passing it to the value attribute of the tag

Comment: you missed a parentheses... and other things like the dollar sign `<%=new java.util.Date(record.attributes.P_Close_Time)%>`

Comment: it would be better if you can post the complete answer. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    Record record = (Record) pageContext.getAttribute("record");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(record.getAttributes().getP_Close_Time())));
%>
```

wth! please, use this code to print classes and post the result so i can figure out what classes you are using:

```
<tbody>
    <c:if
        test="${not empty jsonResult && not empty jsonResult.records}">
        <c:forEach items="${jsonResult.records}" var="record">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:15%;"><img src="${record.attributes.P_Image_Path}" class="img-responsive" /></td>
                <td style="width:15%;">${record.attributes.P_Description}</td>
                <td style="width:55%;">${record.attributes.P_Username_Seller}</td>
                <%
                    //java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                    //System.out.println(sdf.format( new java.util.Date(${record.attributes.P_Close_Time}));
                    Object record = pageContext.getAttribute("record");
                    System.out.println("page record: " + (record == null ? null : record.getClass().getName()));
                %>
                <td style="width:15%;">${record.attributes.P_Close_Time}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your answer. From where the Record object came?

Comment: from `pageContext` or `request` implicit jsp objects (i don't remember if the first or the latter). `c:forEach` stores the current iteration object as an attribute with name = var.

Comment: Sorry not working. It's throwing unknown type Record

Comment: `Record` is your own class... i don't know what's its name... it was just an example!

Comment: sorry there's no object. I mentioned that it's JSON response. in JSON response you don't have objects.